# Use of R for twitter analysis

Tags: quanteda, rtweet

I am using Twitter data for my dissertation. Essentially I want to build a datasheet of tweets from a list of users (usernames) from a set of dates (start/end DTG). I have the names and dates and categories in a seperate CSV. My challenge is I want to scrub through each user's tweets for specific words (in a dictionary), then aggregate those counts so I can plot them across time. I can manage a FOR loop to build each data frame for each user, but I'm lost as to the method to search and count the text. (I'm familar with TAD approaches and building a corpus/tokens). Any help is appreciated

```
#code for dictionary
temp =readtext(paste0(getwd(),"/pivot_dict.xlsx"), header=FALSE)
dict_pivot=temp$text
tweets_users <- read.csv("tweets_users.csv", header=TRUE)
#build vectors of names/positions and dates
usernames <- tweets_users %>% pull(Username)
start_date <-tweets_users %>% pull(StartDTG)
end_date <-tweets_users %>% pull(EndDTG)

#loop through users to get tweets, build a corpus, tokenize 
  i=1#temporary integer
  temp <- get_all_tweets(users = usernames[i], start_tweets = start_date[1], end_tweets = end_date[i], bearer_token = get_bearer(),data_path="Tweets",is_retweet=FALSE, is_reply=FALSE,n = 10000)
# here is where i need to simply the data frame and count terms (from dict_pivot above)
```

Comment: This is not at all hard to do in **quanteda** but we'd need a snippet of your dataset, or a link to the .csv file, to demonstrate.

Comment: I actually managed to figure out my question use the get() command to pass variables to other commands. I used str_detect and my csv dictionaries.

Comment: FYI, code that relies on `get` is often fragile and non-reproducible. In general I discourage using `get` (or the complementary `assign`) in all but very-specific situations.

Comment: Good to know. At my skill level I was proud of figuring it out!